# What is the fastest way to retrieve the header names from xlsx files

Tags: python, powershell

I have the following script to retrieve the header names from `.xlsx` files, but this script response is not fast when I have large size or millions of `.xlsx` files in directory and subdirectory.

```
foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem 'E:\Path_DATA'  -Recurse)) {
if ($file -Like '*.xlsx') {
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application      
    $FileBook = $Excel.workbooks.Open($file.FullName)
    $FileSheet = $FileBook.Worksheets.item(1) #Multiple sheets?
    $FileColumns = $filesheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    $FileHeaders = @() 
    for($i=1;$i -le $FileColumns;$i++){
       $FileHeaders += $FileSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Item(1,$i).Text    
    }
    #$FileHeaders -join "," 
    '"{0}"' -f ($FileHeaders -join '","') 
    $FileBook.Close()
    $Excel.quit()
}
}
```

What is the fastest way to retrieve the `.xlsx` file header naems?

Comment: Filter for the xlsx files in your `Get-ChildItem`. So, `Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xlsx -File -Recurse`. Use `ImportExcel` module but, if you're going to use the ComObject, only call on it once before your loop.

Comment: Is `Install-Module ImportExcel` is one time or Do I need to include this every time I execute the script files?

Comment: Just once. At a new session start up, PowerShell looks in the paths provided in `$env:PSModulePath` to import modules; so there's no need to import, or install modules after the first time. It's a really well-made module so I encourage you to get familiar with it.

Comment: I am getting the error like Import-Excel : The 'Import-Excel' command was found in the module 'ImportExcel', but the module could not be loaded.
For more information, run 'Import-Module ImportExcel'.
At line:3 char:13
`Install-Module ImportExcel
foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xlsx 'E:\Path_DATA'  -Recurse)) {    
    $excel= Import-Excel -Path $file.FullName
    $excel
}`

Comment: You may have to reopen your session again, or just import it for that current session.

Comment: `ImportExcel` module is taking long time to give the output the header names? Here is my script   
`Import-Module ImportExcel
foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xlsx 'E:\PATH_DATA'  -Recurse)) {    
    $excel= Import-Excel -Path $file.FullName
    $excel | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | %{"$($_.Name)"}
}`

Comment: @sridharnetha After you install a module it is available, there is no import it again with each execution. Try something like this: `$files = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xlsx -Path "'E:\PATH_DATA'" -Recurse
foreach($file in $files){
    $excel= Import-Excel -Path $file.FullName
    $excel | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | %{"$($_.Name)"}}`